# Foreach loop duplication php

Tags: php, html, css

My code display the same how in the picture look, instead of displaying
    20
    16.5
    16
    12
Displays one row with 20 four times, another 16.5

This is how I want to look my grade row
   20
    16.5
    16
    12

Thanks in advance.

[image: table]

```
<?php foreach($rowstudent as $rowst): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['lname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['studentcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>

    <?php foreach($rowstudentpoints as $rowsm): ?>
        <th> <?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowsm['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Misunderstand your question. Please specific your request. Your code is not very useful to understand your problem

Comment: What is output of the $rowsm['sum'].

Comment: @VishalSharma 20, 16.5 16, 12

Comment: As i seen in your code that is totally perfect for you requirement ...what is the problem

Comment: @VishalSharma the problem is that's not the order of their grader, like tata is 20, tito 16.5 carolos 16 and karla12

Comment: $rowstudentpoints is suppose to be a header.. or this is the body of the table already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($rowstudent as $k=>$rowst): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['lname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
        <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['studentcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
        <th> <?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';?></th>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your problem was the inner `foreach`, it's getting executed at every row. So what we do is, take the index of the first array `$k` and use it on the on the second array containing the *sum*, that way we can make use of both arrays in one `foreach`.

Comment: Thank for helping me, A question how are you getting the data from $rowsm[$k]['sum], because I getting a error saying that rowsm is undefined

Comment: @I can Has Cheezburger ...How you can access the other array like:- $rowsm without defining in forech

Comment: @CarlosPerez Am sorry, please change `$rowsm` to `$rowstudentpoints`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach($rowstudent as $rowst): ?>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
    <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['lname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
    <th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['studentcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th>
<th><?php echo  htmlentities($rowst['Grade'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') .  htmlentities($rowst['delete'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . htmlentities($rowst['edit'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></th>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```